# Identifying old capacitor

Tags: capacitor, identification, markings, ac-motor, component-values

I need help identifying the capacitor that needs to be replaced. The capacitor was located in the motor of the sewing machine. It is not clear in the pictures, but it says:
.01 + .0005 x 2 and 600WV.DC
[image]
[image]
I also put a picture of the electric motor plate in the attachment.
[image]

Comment: It is probably a noise suppression capacitor. I contacted Bernina about a similar capacitor and they told me to just take it out if I was not worried about the electrical noise created by the machine.

Comment: Ok, thank you. so it is not important to start the motor?

Comment: No, try it without the capacitor.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much!